# Weird Memory leak with XML serializer , new class and DataSet

Tags: .net, class, memory, dataset, xmlserializer

Our application suddenly started have memory leak.  I had successfully  reproduced it with following testing code(DotNet 3.5 or 4.5, visual studio 2013, windows 7/8 64 bit):

- a XMLserializer created with a type of a new class(even it's a empty class),
- A large loop,  create a dataset with one datatable and one datacolumn.
  here is the code :

  ```
  Imports System.Xml
  Imports System.Xml.Serialization
  Module Module1 
    Sub Main()
        Dim x As XmlSerializer
        x = New XmlSerializer(GetType(tClass))    ' needed for reproduce leak  
        Dim ds As DataSet
        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000000
           For j As Integer = 0 To 1000
              ds = New DataSet
              ds.Tables.Add("tb1").Columns.Add("dssd")
           Next
        Next
    End Sub
  End Module
  Public Class tClass  ' empty class
  End Class
  ```

but I still don't know the reason.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Consider cleaning up your code sample's formatting a bit so that people can follow it more easily.  Also, how do you know that you have a memory leak? :)

Comment: No memory leak in Windows 8.  What operating System are you using?  Program runs a long time, but memory doesn't go up in task manager.

Comment: I test it under Windows 7 Enterprise,

Comment: I test it under 64bit  Windows 7 Enterprise, Sp1,  memory usage go up very quickly in task manager, I will try to test it again in windows 8

Comment: 64 bit window 8.1 ,same issue.

Comment: Jdweng,  one of my colleague also told me he did see the leak. but I found he just checked the whole machine memory usage which the memory leak is related small. After he checked the related Processe's memory  usage , He confirmed the leak was happening.

Comment: Get memory profiler and see is it leak or no. What causes a leak.

Answer (score 1):

The memory is being consumed by dynamically generated run-time assemblies created inside the `XmlSerializer` constructor.  From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Dynamically Generated Assemblies**
>
> To increase performance, the XML serialization infrastructure dynamically generates assemblies to serialize and deserialize specified types.

What that means is that, the *first* time you construct an `XmlSerializer` for a specific type, reflection is used to generate c# code that serializes and deserializes the type and all referenced types, which is then linked and loaded into memory.  You can see the reference source code that does this in the [`TempAssembly`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/Compilation.cs) class.  Loading the dynamic assembly consumes memory, and that memory is never released until the [`AppDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) is unloaded.

However, once generated, the dynamic assembly is cached and reused by the runtime in the following situations:

> The infrastructure finds and reuses those assemblies.  This behavior occurs only when using the following constructors:
>
> [`XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s92ee1(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [`XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw0f5wee(v=vs.110).aspx).
>
> If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable...

Since you **are** using the first constructor, your dynamic assembly **is** cached and reused, meaning that the memory consumption is a one-time-only event during the execution of your application *for each root type you serialize*.  As long as you only serialize a finite number of types, the memory used by these dynamic assemblies is bounded and stabilizes fairly quickly.

(If you need to serialize a potentially unlimited number of types because you are doing, say, [dynamic class generation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd554932%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then your memory usage might keep increasing.  But I doubt you are doing that.)